# How to make keyframe animation constant?

Tags: animation, keyframes, animation-nodes

How can I make the animation of the water go on forever? I keyframed from 1-10 and now I want it to go at the same speed forever. I know it's possible but the tutorial for it was unlisted. [image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Linear Extrapolation* or in the *Dope Sheet* window > header menu > *Channel > Extrapolation Mode > Linear Extrapolation*